# Как правильно передавать данные состояния VUE3 Composition API?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

У меня есть домашняя страница, в которой есть компонент Header в котором есть кнопка вызывающее модальное окно, модальное окно это обычный элемент UI с базовыми настройками, в который мне нужно передать HTML с например с регистрацией, но я не совсем понимаю как это правильно сделать при этом храня состояние без Vuex. На данный момент это выглядит вот так:

```
Homepage

controllers
  |__ModalsController.js // тут я планировала хранить состояние модального окна (открыто/закрыто/переключено)

ui
 |__ Heaader.vue //тут кнопка вызывающее конкретное модальное окно (например регистрацию) 
 |__ ModalBase.vue //базовая верстка модального окна 

pages
    |__Login.vue    //верстка модального окна входа
```

Но несколько раз прочитав документацию я не разобралась как это все связать Буду очень признательна если кто-то подскажет. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: А почему вы не хотите использовать VUEX?

Comment: В документах и на хабре многие пишут, что с Composition API,  VUEX не нужен (https://habr.com/ru/company/otus/blog/570138/0)

Comment: Там написано "вам может и не понадобиться". А может и понадобится. Просто странно не пользоваться такой удобной и полезной штукой как VUEX.